# Tetris has stopped working

Tags: java, android

I'm making tetris in Android via eclipse (I use an emulator of eclipse). The program worked untill I added a bunch of stuff (maybe wasn't so smart, but nothing visual was changed so) I didn't run the progam in a while. Now I can go to my first activity, but as soon as I click the button to go to my next one, the program stops working :(

Here is my code:

- `MainActivity.java` http://pastebin.com/P9AAJ90n (button towards `Tetris.java`)
- `Tetris.java` http://pastebin.com/WEsXshPh (probably contains error)
- `TetrisView.java` http://pastebin.com/ejUJjLMk

I think that's the code the problem is located in, but do ask for more if required...
(I think the problem is located in the `onCreate()` method of `Tetris.java`

Now the LogCat Debug text:

http://pastebin.com/MSCxHdsr

Thanks in advance

PS: If I remove the whole `onCreate()` of `Tetris.java` except the first 2 lines, I can run the program.

-----------------------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------------

I removed one of the setContentView(), still stops working. Also looked into DroppedTiles, thought I fixed it but didn't :(

- Logcat: http://pastebin.com/JHu7n1uA
- DroppedTiles: http://pastebin.com/tyKLuxVd
- Block: http://pastebin.com/zmPa7cv7

I commented the DroppedTiles in Tetris.java...

Tried reading the debug log but most of it I do not understand sadly

Comment: your problem seems to be in the DroppedTiles.java, line 29. Can you post the code?

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. I suggest you to look at the line 29 of `DroppedTiles.java`. Something is `null` here.

Comment: Did you write the tetris by yourself?

Comment: Yes I did, I changed the null problem in DroppedTiles.java, there was a null object indeed, thanks for notifying me. I'm starting up my emulator again to see if it works (looks like I need to read debug logs better)

Comment: @AlexanderClaes Yes, learning to read debug log will save you a lot of time.

Comment: @ZouZou Some stupid mistakes everywhere fixed the problem, thanks everyone for helping me out a lil bit! :)

Answer (score 2):

you're setting content view twice

```
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_tetris);
                // Intent intent = getIntent();
```

`// Add mTetrisView to this
            mTetrisView = new TetrisView(this, null);
            setContentView(mTetrisView);
            mTetrisView.init();`

figure out which is the correct one (probably the first) and remove the other.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't solve the problem but good to know for sure! :) PS would it be possible to add the TetrisView over the activity_tetris view?